# Output hidden state in OpenNMT-py

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, seq2seq, opennmt

I just have a short question regarding the pytorch version of OpenNMT. There does not seem to be an option to return the hidden state of encoder and decoder in the options. Am I missing a flag or is this not an option in OpenNMT-py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by the encoder and decoder does not return hidden state?

If you see the [RNNEncoder](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/master/onmt/encoders/rnn_encoder.py), it returns `encoder_final, memory_bank, lengths` where the `memory_bank` represents the hidden state which is of shape `seq_len x batch_size x hidden_size`. And the `encoder_final` is in general used by the decoder in a sequence-to-sequence model.

Now, let's see the [RNNDecoder](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/master/onmt/decoders/decoder.py#L32). As we see, the forward() method returns a FlaotTensor and a dictionary of FlaotTensors.

```
(FloatTensor, dict[str, FloatTensor]):
* dec_outs: output from the decoder (after attn)
  ``(tgt_len, batch, hidden)``.
* attns: distribution over src at each tgt
  ``(tgt_len, batch, src_len)``.
```

Usually, we use the `dec_outs` in sequence-to-sequence tasks. For example, in natural language generation tasks, we feed the `dec_outs` to a softmax layer to predict tokens.

There are several other types of encoders/decoders which you can explore from the following two links.

- https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/tree/master/onmt/encoders
- https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/tree/master/onmt/decoders

Comment: In the memory_bank, how can we distinguish cell state from hidden state for an LSTM model? I don't get a separate value for the cell.